# Filter all Users to show only active ones in admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model, let's call it X, which has a `ManyToManyField` that can list any number of users. In the admin interface (the only place those X objects can be created), I want to filter all the possible users by whether they are active (`is_active=True`) or not. Old instances of X can have inactive users, that is fine. It is just new instances of X that cannot have inactive users added.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to use a custom `form` in your admin class. There, you can set the [`queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField.queryset) parameter of the [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield):

```
# forms.py
class XForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # or whatever the name of the ManyToManyField is
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_active=True))

    class Meta:
        model = X
        fields = '__all__'

# admin.py
class XAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = XForm

site.register(X, XAdmin)
```

Comment: That was far simpler than I was expecting. Many thanks.